# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol gStreamer tutorials Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, gstreamer, lnk2019

After installing gStreamer SDK
[Installed from here](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows) I am now attempting to compile and run the tutorial files that come with it, using Visual studio 2015. [Tutorial documentation here](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Tutorials)

Given that these were originally made in VS2010 I had to upgrade the tutorial projects in order to even use them. Next I had to add my include directories leaving me with only a set of [LNK2019 unresolved external symbol errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx)

At this point I feel solving this is a bit beyond me given the variety of possible causes listed on the msdn website.

For [Tutorial 1](http://docs.gstreamer.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=327735) I have 16 LNK2019 errors eg.

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _gst_object_unref referenced in function _main   basic-tutorial-1

All 16 errors related to the following "external symbols"

_gst_object_unref

_gst_mini_object_unref

_gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered

_gst_element_get_bus

_gst_element_set_state

_gst_parse_launch

_gst_init

Searching file contents in my gStreamer SDK directory I find all these occur in

D:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\lib\libgstreamer-0.10.dll.a

So I am assuming that the issue is related to the linking of the libgstreamer-0.10.dll.a lib.

Anymore details I should provide? Any suggestions?

Comment: `D:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\lib\libgstreamer-0.10.dll.a` Looks like mingw instead of Visual Studio.

Comment: I expect what is missing is you are not linking to the libraries provided with the SDK and this project does not automatically do that for you using pragmas.

Comment: Following link will get you solve the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294685/how-do-i-configure-visual-studio-2017-to-run-gstreamer-tutorials

Answer (score 9):

change the Linker option "Ignore All Default Libraries" to No. works for me

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use that SDK? It's very old & obsolete. Either use fresh installers from GStreamer team (http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/) or cross-compile your app using MinGW packages provided by Fedora / OpenSUSE.

Comment: How to use gstreamer in ios.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be due to the fact I was using the 64bit SDK. The tutorial projects were set up to output 32bit and I believe it may have been expecting 32bit libraries.

After installing the 32bit SDK I was able to compile.

However I am now left with missing libgstreamer-0.10.dll run time error.

While there is the libgstreamer-0.10.dll.a that I mentioned before but the libgstreamer-0.10.dll does not exist in the SDK directory.

But I'll leave that problem for another post if I can't figure it out.