# How do I configure Visual Studio 2017 to run Gstreamer tutorials?

Tags: gstreamer

I am using Windows 10. I am unable to configure Visual Studio 2017 to run basic Gstreamer tutorials. I am getting errors like 'cannot open gst/gst.h'. I am using gstreamer 1.0.

Please help.

Answer (score 16):

Hello my friend.

First of you need to download the library from https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/

You need to download and install both installers for developers and non-developers.

For instance for 1.14 it is the now latest version,

- **gstreamer-1.0-devel-x86-1.14.1.msi**
- **gstreamer-1.0-x86-1.14.1.msi**

You will install and setup both of them in the same directory like `C:\gstreamer`. (I guess gstreamer automatically adds its `/bin` to the Path environment. If not just ask it.)

After that you will open your Visual Studio. Create your C++ project. Create your `main.cpp` file. Right click on your project and click properties.

We need to do 3 steps:

1. Include the necessary directory paths.
2. Define the where the `.lib` paths are.
3. Specify which `.libs` you want to use.

After clicking properties:

1. C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories -> define your include paths such as

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\glib-2.0\include;C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\include\gstreamer-1.0;C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\include\glib-2.0\;C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\include\glib-2.0\glib;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

2. Linker -> General -> Adding Library Directories -> write your lib directory path such as

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
```

3. Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> Write your .lib files you want to use such as

```
gobject-2.0.lib;glib-2.0.lib;gstreamer-1.0.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

`gobject-2.0.lib;glib-2.0.lib;gstreamer-1.0.lib` are the ones we added, others are done by default.

That's all. You can just write in your `main.cpp` file

`#include <gst/gst.h>` and use your GStreamer Library

I think this will work for almost all libraries.

Comment: although the question is about the tutorials: For some simple encoding+streaming code I had to add gstapp-1.0.lib and gstvideo-1.0.lib. Maybe someone can use this information instead of searching in the > 500 files lib folder...

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer to comment on astarakastara's answer.. but don't have the reputation yet.

Note that you probably want to use the "MSVC" version of the install files:
"gstreamer-1.0-devel-msvc-x86_64-1.16.1.msi"
"gstreamer-1.0-msvc-x86_64-1.16.1.msi"

These are new since his/her answer, and include .pbd debugging files made for debugging in visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

Also we need add dll path in the properties

1. Go to Properties->Debugging->Environment
2. Add PATH=C:\path\where\gstreamer\dll\is;$(PATH)
   For ex- PATH=C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin;$(PATH)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you SO MUCH astarakastara, i thought i was lost and alone trying to compile gstreamer on windows and not giving up.

So i would like to update, now you also need to add gstapp-1.0.lib for the additionnal library.

Also tip:, a good way to use/share environemental variable on visual studio is with $(YOUR_VARIABLE)/remaining_path, and then in you windows user environment variable you set YOUR_VARIABLE with multiple values using ";" to separate.
So it's easy to deploy accross multiple machine.

Also don't add the bin folder or you'll have pango dll problem.

-- Dont use vcpkg install, it does not contain gst plugins-goods so you'll be unable load https

-- [gst-build](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-build) is deprecated don't use it, [monorepo](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/) is a pain to install, you'll have to start visual studio developper command prompte, then set it's environment to x64 (by executing vcvars64.bat, or you'll have problem), and compile for a hell of a time, then if everything work, find a way to maje it work.